# Not able to install laravel 5.4 : The requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system

Tags: php, xml, ubuntu-14.04, laravel-5.4

I have already tried and installed using `sudo apt-get install php-xml`,`sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml`, `sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml`

But it showing

> phpunit/phpunit 5.7.0 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP
>   extension xml is missing from your system.

while installing laravel 5.4.

Comment: Check for php CLI config

Comment: didn't get you.what i need to check?

Comment: I think you are runging phpunit from your terminal so u need to check module( php-xml) for php cli version

Comment: upon running command php -m, it's showing libxml, Simplexml, Xmlreader, Xmlwriter

Comment: so .... you never resolved this ... i guess you gave up on using the extension?

Comment: Tried all the available answers. but that didn't resolved my issue.Multiple version of php was existing in my system.So removed everything related to php first. Then made a fresh installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple version of php was existing in my system.So removed everything related to php first. Then made a fresh installation. That solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This might work: `sudo phpenmod xml`.